# "Error loading documents" on Cloud Firestore when console left open for a while

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I noticed a quite new phenomenon which is that when I leave the console open for over a couple of minutes I get an "Error loading documents" error on all my collections until I refresh the page. This never happened before regardless of how long I left it open.

The only thing that has changed was that I was experimenting with the rules, but at the end went back to the default setup.

My question is whether this might have repercussions on how my users access their information. Please see below the current rules (commented are the ones that I published for about 10 minutes to test).

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

//     match /users/{user}/{document=**} {
//       allow read;
//       allow write: if request.auth.uid == user;
//     }

//     match /items/{document=**} {
//       allow read;
//       allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true;
//     }

//     match /completedItems/{document=**} {
//       allow read;
//       allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true;
//     }

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same problem with the database page in console.firebase.google.com. Not only a short period of time after it is displayed but also when I go there for the first time to check a posting.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issues; however, they are not attached to the Firebase rules. I currently have the default Firebase rules yet I'm having an "Error Loading documents"

Comment: I have got the same issue, here's a screenshot: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DaCbsoSW4AANYjh.jpg:large

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. Has anyone reported the problem to Google?

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Reloading the page I get the circle spinning for ages in the documents column and then the message "Error loading documents"

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue but know that firestore is still currently in Beta so remember we're using a product this is still in very active development. I'm sure this is something the Firebase team will resolve sooner than later.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, Any comments? I am facing it now every 20 seconds

Comment: I have the same problem and have to refresh browser every time to view the data

Comment: same here, every time i change the tab to look at something else I need to refresh the console because of this error (same as Ben posted)

Comment: Feb 2020, problem still exists.

Comment: Jep, also having this issue right now. Started one our ago.
In the DevTools I get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" Error and "Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend."
Seems like it cannot even get the firebase client library.

Answer (score 16):

In my case I figured it was Kaspersky antivirus that blocks the request. When I closed it the database successfully loaded.

Answer (score 6):

From the firebase status dashboard issue https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Console/18006:

> We are experiencing an issue with the Cloud Firestore Console where,
>   after a few minutes, it shows an error trying to load documents.
>   Currently, the workaround is to click on another collection or to
>   refresh the browser. We are actively investigating the issue and will
>   post an update once more information is available.

Update: I have reached out to Firebase on 18 April 2018 for any updates on the issue, their response below:

> Sorry, but I couldn't share any timelines or specifics regarding this issue at the moment. Rest assured that this bug is closely monitored, and is being actively worked on by our engineers, as this affects many users such as yourself.

Update 25 April 2018 from Firebase Console:

> The issue with the Cloud Firestore Console where, after a few minutes it would show an error trying to load documents, should have been resolved for all affected projects as of 09:30 US/Pacific. We will conduct an internal investigation of this issue and make appropriate improvements to our systems to prevent or minimize future recurrence.

Comment: This same status is being reported as of April 12, 2018 at least through now (April 20, 2018).  Would be funny if they lifted the message directly from ^ this comment.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the reason was that I had exceeded my daily quota and for some reason it would not show the documents. I'd suggest checking if you've surpassed your daily quota and if so wait until it rolls over to the next day.

Answer (score 4):

For me, it was AdBlock that was making the issue - still, in 2022.
Disable it and it should work fine :)

Comment: Just had this issue in console.cloud.google.com and disabling AdBlock helped me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of turning off Kaspersky you can add it to a list of trusted websites by managing the exclusions. [How to add trusted website](https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/kaspersky-add-exclusion/14765/)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was that I was using Fiddler. I guess the client does some kind of certificate pinning.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because the Chrome extension "CORS Unblock".