# Can't save document using cloud firestore on android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to save a document on a collection, following the documentation on cloud firestore. I can read a collection/document that I manually created on the firebase console but trying to store from my Android app is not working.

Console/Logcat is not showing any error and the app is not crashing.
Neither of the listeners are getting called.
Am I missing something?

```
class UserActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile)
        save_button.setOnClickListener { storeUser() }
    }

    private fun storeUser(){
        val user = HashMap<String,Any>()
        user.put("first", "Ada")
        user.put("last", "Lovelace")
        user.put("born", 1815)

        db.collection("users")
                .add(user)
                .addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference> { documentReference -> Log.d("Storing User", "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.id) })
                .addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener { e -> Log.w("Storing User", "Error adding document", e) })
    }
}
```

EDIT:

As an update trying to read a document throws the following exception

> com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: Failed to
>   get document because the client is offline.

Comment: The success/failure listeners will only be called once the data is committed to, or rejected by, the server. Are you sure you have a connection to the server?

Comment: Do you have the right permissions to save data to the database?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think so, as i said on the question i can read data from the database.

Comment: @AlexMamo I choose the "test" option when creating the database. This are the rules filled by default 
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I needed to add the following permission to the **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But I find this weird because I could login using the firebase auth methods without it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. Kaspersky antivirus is guilty. Disable your antivirus.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50535344/3456124